# Convert Scala neo4j write code to Pyspark in databrick

Tags: python, pyspark, neo4j, databricks

I want to convert the below **scala code to pyspark** in databrick.

```
`enter code here`%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

dfnew
.write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
.option("url", "bolt:url/")
.option("authentication.type", "basic")
.option("authentication.basic.username", "neo4j")
.option("authentication.basic.password", password)
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("relationship", "HAS_DEPT")
.option("relationship.save.strategy", "keys")
.option("relationship.source.labels", ":Employee")
.option("relationship.source.node.keys", "employeeCode")
.option("relationship.source.save.mode", "Match")
.option("relationship.target.labels", ":Department")
.option("relationship.target.node.keys", "DeptCode")
.option("relationship.target.save.mode", "Match")
.save()
```

I have changed it to bellow python code

```
 %python
    import pyspark`
    
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`
    
    
    df.select("employeeCode","Name").write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")\
    .option("url", "bolt://url:7687/")\
    .option("authentication.type", "basic")\
    .option("authentication.basic.username", "neo4j")\
    .option("authentication.basic.password", "password")\
    .mode("OverWrite")\
    .option("relationship", "HAS_DEPT")\
    .option("relationship.save.strategy", "keys")\
    .option("relationship.source.labels", ":Employee")\
    .option("relationship.source.node.keys", "employeeCode")\
    .option("relationship.source.save.mode", "Match")\
    .option("relationship.target.labels", ":Department")\
    .option("relationship.target.node.keys", "DeptCode")\
    .option("relationship.target.save.mode", "Match")\
    .save()
```

but getting the error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
17 .option("relationship.target.labels", ":Department")
18 .option("relationship.target.node.keys", "DeptCode")
---> 19 .option("relationship.target.save.mode", "Match")
20 .save()

Please help me in converting

Comment: have you attached neo4j connector to cluster?

Comment: Yes Alex. I did all. Scala code is working but not the python one

Comment: Can you post bigger stack trace?